# Using Minpack to solve S-curve

Tags: fortran

I'd like to use Minpack (fortran) to estimate the D parameter in the following generalized form of the S-curve: y = (A - D) / (1 + (x**B/C)) + D

[image]

The idea is that in this application, the user provides A [which is always 0 to force passage through (0,0)], B, and C, and from there Minpack will find a value for D that forces passage through (1,y), where y is also supplied by the user but must be <= 1.  I was able to accomplish this task with the code below, however, minpack is claiming it hasn't converged when in fact it appears that it has.  For example, when running this code and entering the values 1 (at the first prompt) and 0 4 0.1 (at the second prompting), minpack returns info = 2, which according to the comments in lmdif means:

*relative error between two consecutive iterates is at most xtol.*

I'm tempted to comment out line 63, but am worried that's playing with fire...are there any seasoned minpack users out there who could comment on this?  Line 63 is the one that reads:

```
if (info /= 1) stop "failed to converge"
```

Am I mis-using Minpack even though it appears to converge (based on my verifying the value in pars)?

```
    module types
    implicit none
    private
    public dp

    integer, parameter :: dp=kind(0d0)

end module

module f_vals 
    DOUBLE PRECISION, SAVE, DIMENSION(:), POINTER:: fixed_vals
end module

module find_fit_module

! This module contains a general function find_fit() for a nonlinear least
! squares fitting. The function can fit any nonlinear expression to any data.

    use minpack, only: lmdif1
    use types, only: dp
    implicit none
    private
    public find_fit

    contains

    subroutine find_fit(data_x, data_y, expr, pars)

    ! Fits the (data_x, data_y) arrays with the function expr(x, pars).
    ! The user can provide any nonlinear function 'expr' depending on any number of
    ! parameters 'pars' and it must return the evaluated expression on the
    ! array 'x'. The arrays 'data_x' and 'data_y' must have the same
    ! length.

        real(dp), intent(in) :: data_x(:), data_y(:)
        interface
            function expr(x, pars) result(y)
            use types, only: dp
            implicit none
            real(dp), intent(in) :: x(:), pars(:)
            real(dp) :: y(size(x))
            end function
        end interface

        real(dp), intent(inout) :: pars(:)

        real(dp) :: tol, fvec(size(data_x))
        integer :: iwa(size(pars)), info, m, n
        real(dp), allocatable :: wa(:)

        tol = sqrt(epsilon(1._dp))
        !tol = 0.001
        m = size(fvec)
        n = size(pars)
        allocate(wa(m*n + 5*n + m))
        call lmdif1(fcn, m, n, pars, fvec, tol, info, iwa, wa, size(wa))

        open(222, FILE='D_Value.txt')
        write(222,4) pars(1)
4       format(E20.12)
        close(222)

        if (info /= 1) stop "failed to converge"

        contains

        subroutine fcn(m, n, x, fvec, iflag)
            integer, intent(in) :: m, n, iflag
            real(dp), intent(in) :: x(n)
            real(dp), intent(out) :: fvec(m)
            ! Suppress compiler warning:
            fvec(1) = iflag
            fvec = data_y - expr(data_x, x)
        end subroutine

    end subroutine

end module


program snwdeplcrv

! Find a nonlinear fit of the form y = (A - D) / (1 + (x**B/C)) + D.

    use find_fit_module, only: find_fit
    use types, only: dp
    use f_vals
    implicit none

    real(dp) :: pars(1), y_int_at_1
    real(dp) :: y(1) = 1.0   ! Initialization of value to be reset by user (y: value of S-curve @ x=1)
    real(dp) :: A, B, C
    integer :: i

    allocate(fixed_vals(3)) ! A, B, C parameters

    pars = [1._dp]  ! D parameter in S-curve function

    ! Read PEST-specified parameters
    write(*,*) '  Enter value that S-curve should equal when SWE=1 (must be <= 1)'
    read(*,*) y_int_at_1
    if(y_int_at_1 > 1.0)  y_int_at_1 = 1
    y = y_int_at_1

    ! Read PEST-specified parameters
    write(*,*) '  Enter S-curve parameters: A, B, & C.  D parameter to be estimated ' 
    read(*,*) A, B, C

    fixed_vals(1) = A
    fixed_vals(2) = B
    fixed_vals(3) = C

    call find_fit([(real(i, dp), i=1,size(y))], y, expression, pars)
    print *, pars

    contains

    function expression(x, pars) result(y)
        use f_vals
        real(dp), intent(in) :: x(:), pars(:)
        real(dp) :: y(size(x))
        real(dp) :: A, B, C, D

        A = fixed_vals(1)
        B = fixed_vals(2)
        C = fixed_vals(3)

        D = pars(1)
        y = (A - D) / (1 + (x**B / C)) + D
    end function

end program
```

Comment: Wouldn't this question rather belong to another community, such as the computational science site, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: "relative error between two consecutive iterates is at most xtol." means that convergence has been reached. Upon iteration, the algorithm found changes *less than xtol*.

Comment: The code above was modified from "example_primes.f90" https://github.com/certik/minpack  I guess the "stop" followed by "failed to converge" is somewhat errant.  I'll remove this line from my code.  Thanks